# How can I use Unicode mappings

Tags: c++, c, unicode, iconv

I found all the nice mappings from various systems to the according [Unicode code points](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/). They are listed in a clear format, which would for sure be easy to parse. But since I don't want to reinvent the wheel is there a C/C++ library using these files to map char arrays from any of those encodings to Unicode?
I only found iconv, but it doesn't seam to support all these mappings (e.g. [Hebrew](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/HEBREW.TXT)) because I couldn't find it in the list of `iconv -l`.

Comment: I'd be incredibly surprised if `iconv` weren't able to do the job. The common hebrew encoding is ISO-8859-8, did you try that?

Comment: ISO-8859-8 is not completely similar to APPLE/HEBREW, which is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iconv -l` lists ISO-8859-8, codepage 862, and MacHebrew on OS X Lion. Maybe they're just not enabled in your OS or it's using an old version of `iconv`.

Comment: Download the source and build your own copy.

Answer (score 3):

[ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/download).

Comment: A bit heavyweight for a simple encoding conversion, but it's a fine library for sure. Might be worth mentioning the `uconv` command-line utility.

Comment: Not my job to make that judgement call. OP asked for libraries that do full Unicode mapping, I named one. And not even the one my employer sells.